# Special character(?) in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query as follows:

```
select [DCC ? Total Sales] from sales
```

The field name is having "?" special character. Because of this the above SQL statement is throwing an error saying

> Invalid Column name

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Change your column name.

Comment: I can't change the column name as it is client's database

Comment: `create view salesview (col1, col2, col3, ...) as select * from sales`. Use this view instead.

Comment: I have read only access, so can't create view

Comment: @user972887: Tell your client why it is a problem, and make them change it. Why the fudge did they use it in the first place?!

Comment: You are definitely working in SQL Server 2008? Not SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: I solved it. Even though the field name have "?" (Question mark), If i write the SQL Query by replacing the "?". It works.

Comment: Not so sure that's the reason. tried it and got no errors. perhaps you misspelled the column name?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Even though the field name have "?" (Question mark), If i write the SQL Query by replacing the "?". It works.

select [DCC ? Total Sales] from sales

The above Query output will work by replacing the "?" even though the column name of the table has the "?"

select [DCC  Total Sales] from sales